# XML format in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I would like to seek help regarding format with XML:

```
<TestFiles>
  <Tests>
    <Emp>
      <FName>Good</FName>
      <LName>Boys</LName>
      <Traits>
        <Trait> 
          <Trait1></Trait1>
          <TraitDesc></TraitDesc>
        <Trait>
        <Trait>
          <Trait2></Trait2>
          <TraitDesc></TraitDesc>
        <Trait>   
        <Trait>
          <Trait3></Trait3>
          <TraitDesc></TraitDesc>
        <Trait>   
      </Traits>  
      <Phone>897-122-222</Phone>
   </Emp>
  </Tests>
</TestFiles>
```

I have trouble in formatting my select statement.  Any Suggestion or Help is really appreciated.

Comment: Sql Server version and more details would help...

Comment: Show what you have tried so far, we don't even know what you are trying to select.

Answer (score 2):

With a query like this:

```
SELECT  
    dbo.emp.FName ,
    dbo.emp.LName ,
    (SELECT 
        ID AS '@ID',
        TraitDesc 
     FROM dbo.Trait t
     WHERE t.EmpID = emp.ID
     FOR XML PATH('Trait'), TYPE) AS 'Traits',
    dbo.emp.Phone
FROM
    emp
FOR XML PATH('Emp'), ROOT('Tests')
```

you can get an output like this:

```
<Tests>
   <Emp>
      <FName>Good</FName>
      <LName>Boys</LName>
      <Traits>
         <Trait ID="1">
            <TraitDesc>Trait #1</TraitDesc>
         </Trait>
         <Trait ID="2">
            <TraitDesc>Trait #2</TraitDesc>
         </Trait>
         <Trait ID="3">
            <TraitDesc>Trait #3</TraitDesc>
         </Trait>
      </Traits>
      <Phone>897-122-222</Phone>
   </Emp>
</Tests>
```

What you probably cannot do (or at least not without dirty hacks and messy code) is having different `<Trait1>, <Trait2>, <Trait3>` XML tags for each child node.